# What is the most cost-effective way to distribute a Bitcoin into 1000 different addresses?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

If I have a wallet/address with 1BTC in it, how can I distribute it to 1000 different addresses (1k new addresses with 0.001BTC in each), paying the least amount of transaction fees?  Sending 1000 near-zero-fee transactions and hope that they all get through in an "acceptable" time is an option I guess, but are there any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best/cheaper way to split a single address into multiple is using batching transactions:

[Batching explained in StackOverflow](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69088/can-someone-please-explain-payment-batching)

This blog post from David Harding shows what are the saving possibilities when using batching to send your transfers and how it works:

[Batching savings](https://bitcointechtalk.com/saving-up-to-80-on-bitcoin-transaction-fees-by-batching-payments-4147ab7009fb)

Samourai Wallet supports [batching](https://blog.samouraiwallet.com/post/170574017907/introducing-batch-spending-for-cheaper-more) if you don't want to use api's.